# Getting Facebook Page's Ratings

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, facebook

I am looking to pull a public Facebook page's ratings into a Ruby on Rails app.

Essentially what I'm looking to do is run a rake task as a cron job that looks for new reviews on one particular Facebook page (the *page* I need will not change) and pulls them into the app. I've explored Facebook's API and the Koala gem and can't get to the page data. I'm just not sure how I can get an access token outside a browser. In addition, if I were to get the access token, it doesn't seem I can get to the ratings data without being the owner of the page.

One route I took was to send a simple `GET` request to the page. Something like `https://graph.facebook.com/{page-id}` works fine, but `https://graph.facebook.com/{page-id}/ratings` throws the following:

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#210) Subject must be a page.",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 210
  }
}
```

What is the simplest way to get to this data?

Comment: _“ it doesn't seem I can get to the ratings data without being the owner of the page”_ – correct. (To be more specific, you need a page access token to read from this connection, _as the documentation clearly states_ – so you need a user that is a manager of the page to grant `manage_pages` permission to your app first.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the question's comments, I needed to be authenticated as a Facebook user with admin access to the Facebook Page of interest because I need to get a token from that.

After getting access to the page, I accomplished the API call via the [Koala gem](https://github.com/arsduo/koala). I initialized Koala with the app:

**config/initializers/facebook.rb**

```
$facebook = Koala::Facebook::OAuth.new(
  "my_facebook_app_id", 
  "my_facebook_secret",
  "my_facebook_redirect_url"
)
```

Since I only needed to get the token for one user in one scenario, I did so via the admin side of my app, in my `facebook_controller`.

In this controller action, I look for the `code` parameter in the route. If we don't find it, we send to the authorization url, otherwise we process and store the Facebook user token in the `User` model in a pre-determined and predictable record.

**app/controllers/admin/facebook_controller.rb**

```
def auth
  if params[:code].present?
    code = params[:code]
    token = $facebook.get_access_token_info(code)
    User.find_by_email('admin@example.com').update(
      :fb_access_token => token['access_token'],
      :fb_token_expires => token['expires'].to_i.seconds.from_now
    )
    redirect_to admin_dashboard_path
  else
    redirect_to $facebook.url_for_oauth_code(:permissions => "manage_pages")
  end
end
```

Once I have an active token, I can acquire the page token like so:

```
user = User.find_by_email('admin@example.com')
user_graph = Koala::Facebook::GraphAPI.new(user.fb_access_token)
accounts = user_graph.get_connections('me', 'accounts')
page_token = accounts[0]['access_token']
page_graph = Koala::Facebook::API.new(page_token)
ratings = page_graph.get_connection('me', 'ratings')
```

At this point, I have the collection of ratings objects stored in the `ratings` variable. I can do whatever I need with these ratings at this point.

*Note: In this particular case, I new the Facebook Page was the first `account` in the array of user accounts. This took some trial and error, but can be accomplished by iterating over the user accounts array (in this case, stored in `accounts`) if you can't predict the index of the desired account.*

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a bug of Facebook Graph API. I have exactly the same problem.

I can get lists of all other objects but I do get an error when requesting /{page-id}/ratings. The JSON payload returned by Facebook Graph API is the following:

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#210) Subject must be a page.", 
    "type": "OAuthException", 
    "code": 210
  }
}
```